# Sustituir una parte de texto en tabla MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Con que sentencia se puede sustituir SOLO una parte del texto de la tabla.

Tengo una tabla que tiene varias entradas con un texto tal que así:

`http://miweb.com/textoquequieromantener`

y quiero que se convierta en esto:

`https://miweb.com/textoquequieromantener`

es decir, quiero cambiar `http://miweb.com` por `https://miweb.com`conservando el texto que viene después de dicho fragmento.

Recién agregué SSL en mi sitio y quiero reemplazar los enlaces guardados en la base de datos.

Comment: Siempre es mismo texto(dirección) o hay variables?

Comment: siempre es una parte igual y otra diferente, es decir, siempre hay una parte que se repite en este casi `http://miweb.com` es la parte que siempre es igual y después de ese trozo de texto, hay otras cosas que son siempre diferentes, yo quiero cambiar esa parte que es igual por otra, que también será igual pero en vez de `http://miweb.com` será `https://miweb.com`

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿en tu tabla **solamente hay direcciones que empiezan así: `http://miweb.com/`** o puede haber **otros tipos de direcciones que no quieres cambiar**, por ejemplo, si hay direcciones así `http://mi-otra-web-que-no-quiero-cambiar`... Si es así las soluciones propuestas te cambiarán **todo**. Es importante que aclares ese punto en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edito**

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
UPDATE tutabla SET tucampo = REPLACE(tucampo, 'http', 'https') where tucampo like 'http://%';
```

<strike>Si quieres modificar toda la tabla no uses where o filtra los resultados que necesites</strike>. Como dicen en los comentarios, mi propuesta anterior llevaría a error, con este cambio funcionará correctamente

Comment: Ojo que así se reemplazaría `https://miweb/mipaginahttps` por `httpss://miweb/mipaginahttpss`

Comment: ¿Y por qué no reemplazar mejor esto `http://miweb.com` por esto `https://miweb.com`?  En la tabla/columna puede haber otros enlaces a páginas que no deben ser reemplazados por `https`. Eso no queda claro en la pregunta, y una vez ejecutada esta consulta, va a ser complicado revertirla si ocurre algo así.

Answer (score 3):

Casi autoexplicativo:

```
update tutabla
   set columna = concat('https://miweb.com', substr(columna, length('http://miweb.com') + 1))
 where columna like 'http://miweb.com%';
```

- Esto garantiza que el `http://miweb.com` esté al inicio del campo, y no en cualquier parte (como en el medio del texto).

Demo: http://rextester.com/DXQR93845